# Blocking specific urn on tomcat webapp

Tags: tomcat

Have a specific need where we need to block a specific urn under a web app 
Eg we have a web app /siebel , under it /siebel/app/ this should work , but the /siebel/smc should not

Tried giving the context path as under the /META-INF folder context.xml

```
<Context path="/siebel/smc" debug="0" privileged="true">
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" 
  allow="127.0.0.1"/>
</Context>
```

also tried

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/siebel/smc">
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1" />
</Context>
```

This ends up in blocking both urls /siebel/smc and /siebel/app

Tried adding the context path in server.xml as well , same result. 
Played with deny option with deny="*" , but still same.

Is there any way to handle this ?

Thanks

Comment: Block it completely, or block it form everyone apart from localhost?

Comment: either should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then. You have the right idea but are applying it in the wrong location. `META-INF/context.xml` applies only to the web application it is placed in and the path attribute is ignored (the path will be derived from the WAR/dir name).

I am assuming you have a web application deployed at `webapps/siebel.war` or `webapps/siebel` and that the context path for that web application is '/siebel`.

We are going to take advantage of a requirement of the Servlet specification which is, when matching URIs to web applications, filters and servlets, the first step is to select the web application by finding the longest matching context path. Therefore if we deploy a new web application to `/siebel/smc` and block all access this should have the effect you want.

Assuming a default Tomcat installation (with unchanged engine and host names) place the following content at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/siebel#smc.xml`

```
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" deny=".*"/>
</Context>
```

You will also need to create the empty directory `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/siebel#smc`

Comment: just incase if we need to allow only from our bastion host/local host , instead of deny , will allow from bastion host work ?

Comment: No. You'll get 404's because all of the requests will be routed to the empty Context. There are several ways to lock down a particular path to localhost only. The rewrite valve (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html) is probably how I'd do it with a condition rewrite to a 403 unless the remote host was localhost.